# SharePoint PowerShell Working C# Not working

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, onedrive

#### This is PowerShell, this code working fine.

###### This PowerShell working however `C#` mentioned below with same dll file is not working

```
# Load SharePoint Client Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

# Function to recursively upload a folder and its contents

# Specify local folder path

# Specify the User account for an Office 365 global admin in your organization
$AdminAccount = "fname.lname@domain.com"
$AdminPass = "MyPassword"

# Specify User's OneDrive Site URL and Folder name
$OneDriveURL = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/personal/fname_lname_doamin_com/"
$DocumentLibrary = "Documents"

# Connect and Load OneDrive Library and Root Folder
$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $AdminPass -AsPlainText -Force
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($OneDriveURL)
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($AdminAccount,$SecurePass)

Write-Host $sss
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

Try {
    $List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocumentLibrary)
    $Ctx.Load($List)
    $Ctx.Load($List.RootFolder)
    
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host $List.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl

} catch {
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor "Red"
}
```

---

### This C# not working, despite using same .dll file

I'm not sure, why this is not working despite heaving same library.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string AdminAccount = "fname.lname@domain.com";
    string AdminPass = "MyPassword";
    string defaultSite = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/personal/fname_lname_doamin_com/";
    String DocumentLibrary = "Documents";
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials ss = new(AdminAccount, GetPassword(AdminPass));

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext clientContext = new(defaultSite)
    {
        Credentials = ss
    };

    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocumentLibrary);

    clientContext.Load(list);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


}
static public SecureString GetPassword(string PassS)
{
    char[] Pass = PassS.ToCharArray();
    var pwd = new SecureString();
    {
        {
            foreach (char c in Pass)
            {
                pwd.AppendChar(c);
            }
        }
        return pwd;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this is not working despite having the same library. This PowerShell script works fine, but the C# code below with the same dll file is not working. It throws an exception when I try to run it. Maybe there is something wrong with the syntax or the references. I have checked the documentation, but I can't find any solution. Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Hi, it will be helpful if you could include the error/exception that you are receiving as part of the question. You can also implement a try/catch clause surrounding the code within the main method to catch the exception and include the message in the post.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
Message:
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'